# How to distinguish the value selected in a drop down menu

Tags: drop-down-menu, vbscript

I have 3 drop down lists. The choices begin with "Dating" or "Married". I am trying to assign a text input "Address1" to "Dating 1:" if selected, or a different text input "Address2" if they are Married 2:. How do I look at the string and get the start of it and apply the correct Address1 or 2 input to that selection? [image: Sample Image]

```
If (TCSelection.TCSDropDown1.List(0)) <> Empty Then

    Else
        TCSDropDown1.AddItem "Dating 1: Couple 1"
        TCSDropDown1.AddItem "Dating 1: Couple 2"
        TCSDropDown1.AddItem "Dating 1: Couple 3"
        TCSDropDown1.AddItem "Married 2: Couple 1"
        TCSDropDown1.AddItem "Married 2: Couple 2"
        TCSDropDown1.AddItem "Married 2: Couple 3"
End If
End Sub

If TCSelection.Address1Input.Text Or TCSelection.Address2Input.Text <> Empty Then
            Address = TCSelection.Address1Input.Text Or TCSelection.Address2Input.Text
            Set client = CreateObject("Couple.Address")
```

Comment: Any thoughts from community?

Comment: You already asked this question I believe.

Comment: Yes, I deleted the post because it wasn't straight forward. Even with the original, no one had input on how to know if "Dating 1:" or "Dating2:" is selected. Thank you.